# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hello Everyone I have used jquery to generate a textbox.It is generated dynamically through jquery.Now the problem is i want to fetch the textbox value in ajax function and then ajax pass this value to other php page which i have mentioned.When i type a text on textbox it gives me alert the value which i have type when i click submit button but it did not pass this value to other page because it gives error :

> -Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

My code is:-
In first script i used to generate texbox dynamically and in second script i want to fetch the value of textbox and pass that value to php file.
In second script i have above error in this line
`dynamic_text.push($(this).parents("tr").find(".dynamic_text").val())`

```
<script>
  jQuery(function($){  
   $(".select_drop").on('change', function(){
     var $this = $(this),
         selectedType = $this.val();
     if($this.closest('tr').find('.dynamic_text').length == 0) $(this).closest('tr').append("<table><tr><td><form method='post'><input type='text' class='dynamic_text'><td></form></td></tr></table>")
     //if($this.closest('tr').find('.dynamic_text').length == 0) $(this).closest('tr').append("<form method='post'><td><input type='text' class='dynamic_text'></td></form>")
    });
  });
  </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){
  <?php global $store; ?>
             var store= '<?php echo $store; ?>'; 
 var textbox = [];
   var textbox1 = [];
    var check = [];
    //var dynamic_text= $('.dynamic_text').val();
var dynamic_text;
   // alert(dynamic_text);
   $('.check').each(function() {
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
               var current = $(this).val();

              //alert(current);
             textbox.push($(this).parents("tr").find(".textbox").val())
             textbox1.push($(this).parents("tr").find(".textbox1").val())
            dynamic_text.push($(this).parents("tr").find(".dynamic_text").val())

         }
  check.push($(this).val());
});

               $.ajax({
             url: 'aj2.php',
             type: 'post',
             data: { check: textbox, store: store, oldval: textbox1,dynamic_text:dynamic_text},
             success:function(data){
              alert(data);
 //alert("Data save!!!");
             }
         });
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Edit :  highlight the error

Comment: Just give us the code, don't put it in an image.

Comment: Post the code *here*

Comment: `dynamic_text` was never defined. So clearly it doesn't have a `.push()` method as it's not an array; as the error states `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: Sir i have added my code in answer please see it and tell me how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not setting a value to the variable `dynamic_text`:

```
 var dynamic_text;
```

As such it's value will be `undefined`. And clearly `undefined` doesn't have a `.push()` method; that's what the error is saying:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

You will want to define your variable as an array:

```
var dynamic_text = [];
```

Comment: thanyou sir for giving me answer.